# Update UI after requestAccessToAccountsWithType

Tags: facebook, macos, cocoa, slrequest

I'm developing an app to help me understand OBJECTIVE-X/OSX.

The app simply connects to Facebook and sends a notification using `NSUserNotification`.
It is working fine, but now I want to add some UI to the mix.

To make the example simpler, I want to update a label (`NSTextField`) to show the status of the Facebook connection.

1. Connecting…
2. Connected
3. Failed

I have the following code in one File `FacebookRequest.m`

```
- (void) connectFacebook{

    if(self.account == nil){
        self.account = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    }

   ACAccountType *facebookAccount = [self.account 
            accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"MY_CODE",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email", 
                                                         @"user_about_me",
                                                         @"user_likes",
                                                         @"manage_notifications",
                                                         @"user_activities"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };
    [self.account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccount 
                                          options:options 
                                       completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){

        if(success){
            NSArray *accounts = [self.account accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccount];
            self.account = [accounts lastObject];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Erro %@", [error description]);
        }

    }];

}
```

and the following one in my `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.statusFacebook setStringValue:@"Connecting…"];
    FacebookRequest *request = [[FacebookRequest alloc]init];
    [request connectFacebook];
}
```

What is the best way to update the UI after the request is complete and I have an account?

I'm having troubles since the request is asynchronous and I can't return any value inside the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` block. Another point is that if I put some "ifs" to check if my account is nil after it, it will be executed before the block has finished executing, so the account would still be `nil`.

Thanks!

PS.: Sorry for the English if it is not clear enough.

Comment: Why can't you just update UI in if(success) ??

Comment: once you've got an account just perform a selector on main thread and that's it..

Comment: @Stats Thanks, I will try that. I'm having troubles because they are in separate files/class I think I will put them in the same file so it will be easier for me =p

Comment: You should better post a nsnotification for that purpose

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for! thanks so much! I will look about NSNotification then

Comment: Ok, then I post the answer and you accept it, ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `NSNotificationCenter` for this purpose:

```
[self.account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccount 
                                          options:options 
                                       completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){

        if(success){
            NSArray *accounts = [self.account accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccount];
            self.account = [accounts lastObject];
            // You post a notification that the UI should update here
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateUI" object:nil];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Erro %@", [error description]);
        }

    }];
```

Then, you add your viewController that should update its UI as an observer of this notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateUI) name:@"UpdateUI" object:nil];

}
- (void)updateUI {
    // Here you actually update your UI
}
```

p.s. if you are not using arc you also remove the observer in dealloc:

```
 - (void)dealloc {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```